# apply gradient and shadow simultaneously with different colors on TextView Android

Tags: android, shader, shadow

I am trying to apply gradient and shadow simultaneously with different colors on TextView. Whenever I apply gradient(shader) it also redraws the shadow with the same color as gradient has, but I need both shadow and gradient with different colors.
Here is some of my code for gradient and shadow:

```
txtHello.setShadowLayer(shadowRadius, tempShadowX,tempShadowY, getShadowColorCode());
radialGradient = new RadialGradient(txtHello.getWidth()/2,txtHello.getHeight()/2,10,color,position,tile_mode);
txtHello.getPaint().setShader(radialGradient)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever shader applied on textView you cant change the color of shadow.its necessary to set shader to null first and then apply shadow layer and text color with different colors

Comment: can you please give me one example of this step?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved:
you can apply change the shadow of a textured or gradient applied text that is

1. First save the shader if you have already applied on text.
2. Second make shader null so that shader effect disappear so a little bit of time
3. Then apply shadow Layer on text
4. Save the shadow Layer
5. Clear Shadow layer
6. Apply shader
7. then save the shader

Now you have a text having shader(gradient/textured) applied with custom color.

```
    Shader shader = getPaint().getShader();
    getPaint().setShader(null);
    getPaint().setShadowLayer(20,  10, 10, Color.BLACK);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    getPaint().clearShadowLayer();
    getPaint().setShader(shader);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
```