# How to apply gradient and shadow simultaneously with different colors on text view android?

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, android-custom-view

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
    val mShader = paint.shader
    paint.shader = null
    paint.setShadowLayer(
        mShadowRadius,
        mShadowDx,
        mShadowDy,
        mShadowColor
    )
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    paint.clearShadowLayer()
    paint.shader = mShader ?: getGradient()
    super.onDraw(canvas)
}
```

Above code adds gradient and shadow correctly but here we are calling onDraw() two times. Can we achieve this by calling onDraw() just one time.

[medium link](https://medium.com/@stepango/android-text-and-linear-gradient-shader-14512fd40e4b).

Comment: similar question :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34489494/apply-gradient-and-shadow-simultaneously-with-different-colors-on-textview-andro

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work around, with this I am able to draw all three shadow, stroke with gradient and text with gradient. I need to call super.onDraw(canvas) multiple time.
it does impact performance.

```
    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {

    if (shadowRadius != 0f) {
        drawShadow()
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        paint.clearShadowLayer()
    }

    if (strokeWidth != 0f) {
        drawStroke()
        super.onDraw(canvas)
    }
    drawText()
    super.onDraw(canvas)
}

    private fun drawShadow() {
    paint.shader = null
    paint.setShadowLayer(
        shadowRadius, shadowDx, shadowDy, shadowColor
    )
}

    private fun drawStroke() {
    this.paint.let {
        it.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        it.strokeJoin = Paint.Join.MITER
        it.strokeWidth = strokeWidth
        // for gradient in stroke add shader
        it.shader = grandient()
        // for solid color of stroke
        it.color = strokeColor
        setTextColor(it.color)
    }
}

    private fun drawText() {
    paint.let {
        it.style = Paint.Style.FILL
        it.strokeWidth = 0f
        // for gradient in text add shader
        it.shader = mTextGradient
        // for solid color of stroke
        it.color = textColor
        setTextColor(it.color)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34671128)